# How to remove parent pages from child slugs on WordPress without a plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, url, permalinks, slug

Say I have pages like this:

- example.org/parent
- example.org/parent/child-one
- example.org/parent/child-two

I would want to take Child Two and make the url just **example.org/child-two** without the hierarchy changing overall.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/page_link/

This hook did not seem to really be enough. It allows for changing the url, but then the page shows 404 as it doesn't find anything.

Is there a need to mess with the permalinks and rewrite rules, or what is needed to make this happen fully?